# Find number of files with a specific extension, in all subdirectories

Tags: c#, file, recursion

Is there a way to find the number of files of a specific type without having to loop through all results inn a Directory.GetFiles() or similar method? I am looking for something like this:

```
int ComponentCount = MagicFindFileCount(@"c:\windows\system32", "*.dll");
```

I know that I can make a recursive function to call Directory.GetFiles , but it would be much cleaner if I could do this without all the iterating.

**EDIT:** If it is not possible to do this without recursing and iterating yourself, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use the [Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) overload of Directory.GetFiles().

Path specifies the path, searchPattern specifies your wildcards (e.g., *, *.format) and SearchOption provides the option to include subdirectories.

The Length property of the return array of this search will provide the proper file count for your particular search pattern and option:

```
string[] files = directory.GetFiles(@"c:\windows\system32", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

return files.Length;
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively you can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
return Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\windows\system32", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

Comment: This has a massive performance issue with large number of files.

Comment: @Aim - Can you  (or anybody else) please quantify your statement?  How slow is 'massive performance issue'?  How many is 'large number of files'?  Jon solution works for me but I'd like to know when/how it could become problematic.

Comment: @DavidHAust The reason being that [`GetFiles` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) will materialize the *entire* list of files that are in a directory.  The preferred method to call now is [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) as it will stream the files back (through a `yield`-like mechanism) as the underlying call to the OS yields the results back.

Comment: OP is dated 2008...well before Directory.EnumerateFiles was even a glimmer in its daddy's eye. Don't be so quick to jump into old posts to shoot answers down because new technology is available.

Comment: Also, `EnumerateFiles` is considerably slower: if you need the scalability, that's OK, but there's no reason to take the hit in most cases.

Answer (score 8):

The slickest method woud be to use linq:

```
var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"H:\iPod_Control\Music", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    select file).Count();
```

Comment: why not `Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"H:\iPod_Control\Music", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this overload of GetFiles:

> [Directory.GetFiles Method (String,
> String, SearchOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx))

and this member of SearchOption:

> **AllDirectories** - Includes the current
> directory and all the subdirectories
> in a search operation. This option
> includes reparse points like mounted
> drives and symbolic links in the
> search.

GetFiles returns an array of string so you can just get the Length which is the number of files found.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a more optimized version. Since I haven't found it, I decided to code it and share it here:

```
    public static int GetFileCount(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        var fileCount = 0;
        var fileIter = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption);
        foreach (var file in fileIter)
            fileCount++;
        return fileCount;
    }
```

All the solutions using the GetFiles/GetDirectories are kind of slow since all those objects need to be created. Using the enumeration, it doesn't create any temporary objects (FileInfo/DirectoryInfo).

see Remarks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx for more information

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion your MagicFindFileCount would look like this:

```
private int MagicFindFileCount( string strDirectory, string strFilter ) {
     int nFiles = Directory.GetFiles( strDirectory, strFilter ).Length;

     foreach( String dir in Directory.GetDirectories( strDirectory ) ) {
        nFiles += GetNumberOfFiles(dir, strFilter);
     }

     return nFiles;
  }
```

Though [Jon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570/find-number-of-files-in-all-subdirectories#27584) might be the better one.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app which generates counts of the directories and files in a parent directory. Some of the directories contain thousands of sub directories with thousands of files in each. To do this whilst maintaining a responsive ui I do the following ( sending the path to *ADirectoryPathWasSelected* method):

```
public class DirectoryFileCounter
{
    int mDirectoriesToRead = 0;

    // Pass this method the parent directory path
    public void ADirectoryPathWasSelected(string path)
    {
        // create a task to do this in the background for responsive ui
        // state is the path
        Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the first layer of sub directories
                this.AddCountFilesAndFolders(state.ToString())


             }
             catch // Add Handlers for exceptions
             {}
        }, path));
    }

    // This method is called recursively
    private void AddCountFilesAndFolders(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            // Only doing the top directory to prevent an exception from stopping the entire recursion
            var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            // calling class is tracking the count of directories
            this.mDirectoriesToRead += directories.Count();

            // get the child directories
            // this uses an extension method to the IEnumerable<V> interface,
           // which will run a function on an object. In this case 'd' is the 
           // collection of directories
            directories.ActionOnEnumerable(d => AddCountFilesAndFolders(d));
        }
        catch // Add Handlers for exceptions
        {
        }
        try
        {
            // count the files in the directory
            this.mFilesToRead += Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Count();
        }
        catch// Add Handlers for exceptions
        { }
    }
}
// Extension class
public static class Extensions
{ 
    // this runs the supplied method on each object in the supplied enumerable
    public static void ActionOnEnumerable<V>(this IEnumerable<V> nodes,Action<V> doit)
    {

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {   
            doit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has to do the iterating part.

AFAIK, there is no such method present in .NET already, so I guess that someone has to be you.