# Find the count of text files in a directory recursively

Tags: c#

I am trying to make some code to count all text files in a directory and its sub directories. I have tried below code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27584/181771

Answer (score 3):

To search **TXT** files in **folder AND it's subdirectories**, use:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: thanks.. now i can filter text files..

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through directories.  There is already a .NET facility to perform this action.

To get a list of files with a certain extension including sub directories, use,

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcDir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    int fileCount = GetFileCount(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);        
}
```

Get text file count from parent and all sub-directories recursively,

```
private int GetFileCount(string s)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.txt").Count() + Directory.GetDirectories(s).Select(GetFileCount).Sum();
}
```

Comment: Good recursive little function, but there is already a third overload for `GetFiles()` that allows searching of sub directories.

Comment: I just noticed from the other answers. :)